# set of figures alignment

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment

I am trying to align a set of 4 figures but it seems I can't do that for the second set.

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1.00\linewidth]{upper.jpg}
\caption{Ψηφιακό αποτύπωμα εκμαγείου άνω γνάθου}
\label{fig176:a}
\vspace{4ex}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1.00\linewidth]{loewwer.jpg}
\caption{Ψηφιακό αποτύπωμα εκμαγείου κάτω γνάθου}
\label{fig176:b}
\vspace{4ex}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1.00\linewidth, height=6cm]{Cbucalb.jpg}
\caption{Ψηφιακό αποτύπωμα εκμαγείων άνω και κάτω γνάθου σε σύγκλειση.}
\label{fig176:c}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1.00\linewidth, height=6cm]{biocopyb.jpg}
\caption{Ψηφιακό αποτύπωμα εκμαγείου κάτω γνάθου, το οποίο θα χρησιμοποιηθεί από το λογισμικό για την αντιγραφή του νεογιλού γομφίου}
\label{fig176:d}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Η σειρά των παραπάνω εικόνων αποτελεί τον αναγκαίο αριθμό ενδοστοματικών σαρώσεων για την δημιουργία μιας αποκατάστασης στον νεογιλό γομφίο.}
\label{fig159}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: There's probably a more straightforward way to do this, but if you add two dummy lines at the end of the third caption, the matching height of the captions will result in the desired alignment. At the end of the caption, you can add `\\ \phantom{xxx xxx}\\`. The `\phantom` is present to avoid an "Underfull 10000" message (there will still be a smaller underfull message); and while it's generally discouraged to use `\\ ` to break text lines, using it here is not unreasonable for a quick fix. Of course, if you have a list of figures, you will need to use an optional form for the changed caption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change all four instances -- or at least the 3rd and 4th -- of `\begin{subfigure}[b]{...}` to `\begin{subfigure}[t]{...}`. I.e., change from bottom-alignment to top-alignment of the `subfigure` environments.

Incidentally, none of the four `\centering` instructions are needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % omit 'demo' option in real doc.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx,lmodern}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.475\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{upper.jpg}
\caption{Ψηφιακό αποτύπωμα εκμαγείου άνω γνάθου}
\label{fig176:a}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.475\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{loewwer.jpg}
\caption{Ψηφιακό αποτύπωμα εκμαγείου κάτω γνάθου}
\label{fig176:b}
\end{subfigure}

\vspace{4ex}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.475\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth, height=6cm]{Cbucalb.jpg}
\caption{Ψηφιακό αποτύπωμα εκμαγείων άνω και κάτω γνάθου σε σύγκλειση.}
\label{fig176:c}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.475\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth, height=6cm]{biocopyb.jpg}
\caption{Ψηφιακό αποτύπωμα εκμαγείου κάτω γνάθου, το οποίο θα χρησιμοποιηθεί από το λογισμικό για την αντιγραφή του νεογιλού γομφίου}
\label{fig176:d}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Η σειρά των παραπάνω εικόνων αποτελεί τον αναγκαίο αριθμό ενδοστοματικών σαρώσεων για την δημιουργία μιας αποκατάστασης στον νεογιλό γομφίο.}
\label{fig159}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```